# java paypal api call certificate is requierd?

Tags: java, api, paypal, certificate

I am using Java & paypal express checkout & DoDirectPayment, i see there are two options either by 
signature given by paypal sandbox merchant account or signature given by paypal sandbox merchant account.

Do i need any certificate if i am using "signature" string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
At SandBox, those two Credentials (generated at SandBox primary account and test account) are same. It is for your convenience.

Do i need any certificate if i am using "signature" string? No, you do not need certificate if you use Signature. You cannot even create both in single paypal account. **API Signature is new way of accessing API**; even PayPal recommands using API Signature.