# Prestashop PayPal Module: Not loading after clicking with "pay with paypal"

Tags: api, paypal, connection, prestashop

On the page in which the selection for payment method is made, paypal is not working. It used to work and i actually received a payment last monday, the 18th of March. 
But now when i click on "pay with paypal", the page keeps loading and eventually sends this message to clients ;

> Please try to contact the merchant:
>   PayPal response:
>
> ->

So the module has actually worked before but seized to work all of a sudden. Prestashop 1.4.7.3, PayPal 3.4.6

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in modules/paypal/api/paypal_connect.php, look for "verbose", and set it to "false" instead of "true".

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's read this about the same problem:

"When you don't have any error messages it is because PayPal did not send any response. This error appends when your server IP has been banned from PayPal. This error often occurs when you are on a shared hosting platform because of hacks attempts but it could also occurs on dedicated hosting for the same reason" (http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PNM-1199?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs)

Try to use another server with another IP. There is a man that said that it works (http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-8608?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

This error because of no return in both functions inside

```
paypal/api/paypal_connect.php 

_connectByFSOCK

_connectByCURL
```

Both these functions are return false may be differences are between Certificate and Signature but remember Signature is the [preferred way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256316/java-paypal-api-call-certificate-is-requierd/5668166#5668166) of accessing PayPal API.

you should check $url and #host in the above image may be not available any more.. in my case I changed mode to live and working fine but still in testing mode not working ... I think because of PayPal API not wor

[image]